# In a Makefile, is "VARIABLE = value" equal to "VARIABLE=value?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Simple question but there are so many things to consider in make that it feels better if I ask this question:

Is `VARIABLE = value` equal to `VARIABLE=value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they're the same. Per [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html):

> Whitespace around the variable name and immediately after the ‘=’ is
>   ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, although `VARIABLE := value` is the same as `VARIABLE:=value`, but

```
VARIABLE:=$(undefined) value
# now VARIABLE is prepended with a space
```

is NOT. This is why the make's manual says "ignored *immediately* after equal sign".

Also, operator `+=` always adds a space.